# Get sorted dict values

Tags: python

How would I get the dictionary values based on the sorted key? For example:

```
d = {
     'first': 'asdf'
     'second': 'aaaa'
}

==> ['asdf', 'aaaa']
```

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
sorted(x.item(), sort=...)
```

How would this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a Python dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use sorted keys:

```
d = {'first': 'asdf', 'second': 'aaaa'}
values = [d[x] for x in sorted(d)]
```

Comment: no need to use `.keys()`. Just `d` will iterate the keys

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension like so:

```
>>> d = {
...          'first': 'asdf',
...          'second': 'aaaa'
...     }
>>> [item[1] for item in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])]
['asdf', 'aaaa']
```